# SVN accept expired certificate with expired root certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, svn

I need to push some code to a server which has woefully out of date certs. The cert expired 2000 days ago, and the root cert expired a month ago. I attempted to use the solutions posted in dozens of answers, using both --trust-server-cert and --trust-server-cert-failures options to force SVN to accept the certificate, however it was not effective. I receive the same error when attempting to authenticate with --username --password.

[image]

Note: the authentication cache was cleared before each attempt.

Since it is a 500 error, I think there is a problem server side, in which case I'm not entirely sure which certificate the error is referring to. However I do not have access to the server (otherwise I would have just updated the cert).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid all rejections caused by your client software, the drastic solution is to  use a system with the date set to when all the certificates were valid. You can either temporarily change the date on your system or use a virtual machine that mounts the relevant directories from your host machine.

Comment: I'll give that a try if I don't get a better solution. It sounds like it would work though

Comment: At the moment group policy has time and date settings locked, but I'll get admin access and try this out.

Comment: If you are on a machine with group policy, you may prefer the virtual machine option. There's less chance of unwanted interactions with the Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both `--non-interactive --trust-server-cert` at the same time.

**Edit 1:**
You can bypass the current certificates by using a ssl proxy like: https://github.com/suyashkumar/ssl-proxy

Comment: I'm not sure if you have images blocked, but yes that's exactly what I did; "svn log --trust-server-cert --non-interactive" and "svn log --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,expired,not-yet-valid,other" both failed with the same error as shown above. If you are having trouble viewing images, please try this direct link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4lwU.png

Comment: Could you use WireShark to make a network capture of the traffic between you SVN client and server? In the SSL traffic there is a packet containing "ALERT" protocol. This will explain which certificate was rejected and why.

Comment: Like I said, the cert expired 2000 days ago, and the root cert a month ago. That's the reason why the cert has been rejected.

Answer (score -1):

There is no solution other than to generate a new certificate for the server.